# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Clients'

Tags: c#

I have a variable which I am populating with records from my database. I then will display this list on a view as a Drop down box. However, it fails once it reaches the drop down.

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Review() {
            var reviews = reviewRepo.GetAllReviews();

            var clients = clientRepo.Clients();    

            List<SelectListItem> items = new SelectList(clients, "ClientID", "ClientName").ToList();
            items.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Default", Value = "0" }));
            ViewBag.ListOfClients = items;

            IEnumerable<AdminReviewViewModel> model = reviews.Select(s => new AdminReviewViewModel() {
                ClientID = s.ClientID,
                ReviewID = s.ReviewID,
                ReviewName = s.ReviewName,
                ReviewPeriodID = s.ReviewPeriodID,
                ReviewPeriodName = s.ReviewPeriod
            });

            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Review", "UserAdmin", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.DropDownList("Clients", ViewBag.ListOfClients as SelectList, new { @class = "GRDropDown", @id = "ReportDD"})
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: It is, sorry. I should have explained more. My list will bring back 3 Clients, I would just like to append a record to the top saying default. So if a user selects default, they will see all 3 clients data

Comment: I have found out how to do it anyway, I just receive a separate error instead. Ill update my question

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. The clue was very much in the error message. It was complaining that there was not Client. This was because in my drop down box was expecting ClientID and ClientName. But instead it receives Value and Text. So I changed my drop down to look like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Clients", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfClients, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "GRDropDown", @id = "ReportDD" })
```

Comment: @Heyyou Thank you for trying :)